# Смена цвета текста через drawable

Tags: android

Есть кнопка:

```
android:background="@drawable/login_button"
android:textColor="@drawable/transparent_button_text_color"
```

В `@drawable/login_button` я сделал так, чтобы менялся цвет кнопки пока кнопка нажата, и собственно нужно поменять цвет текста
В `@drawable/transparent_button_text_color` написал следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

И вот проблема: в Design View цвет кнопки отображается фиолетовым, а когда запускаю приложение - ошибка
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: @s8am `Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class Button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, скорее всего, не туда ссылаетесь.

Попробуйте в файле `@drawable/transparent_button_text_color` заменить `android:drawable` на `android:color`.

Answer (score 0):

замените drawable на color
Drawable это картинки а Color это цвет в Xml файле

android:background="@drawable/login_button"
android:textColor="@drawable/transparent_button_text_color"